# saving html looses values inside text area

Tags: jquery

I have a table with inputs and textareas inside some td's. These inputs and textareas are empty when my page is loaded. I then enter text inside both, the inputs and textareas. I then save this page to a sql database. I then am able to load this table when desired. When the page is loaded, I of coarse need all the text "values" in all inputs and textareas to be loaded.

I am using this in a function to keep all values of inputs.

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

Works fine. But when trying to apply this to a textarea as shown bellow no luck.

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

When I load my saved html, my text area is empty but the value="" takes the text though.  For example when I load a empty table, the textarea looks like this.

```
<textarea value="" type="text"></textarea>
```

Once I have typed "hello" in the textarea, and saved my html, I end up with this when loading it

```
<textarea value="hello" type="text"></textarea>
```

But the actual textarea is empty.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Because `textarea` is different than `input` and the text goes in the `textarea` itself not in an attribute.

So to change/set the textarea content you need to use the `$('textarea').val('hello');` or if it is in the `$.each()` then `$(this).val('hello');`

> not sure I understood what I'm supposed to there? –  Adrien Boufflet 1
>   hour ago

I don't know how/when you are applying the `value` of textarea but when you do you should use `.val('some text')` instead of `.attr('value', 'some text')`

I hope this explains it better.

Comment: thank you for replying. I have edited my question because I think it wasn't quiet clear actually. I understood your answer above but it doesn't seem to be what i need. I do not want to replace text but just keep it

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).text(this.value));
});
```

was getting `.val()` and not `.text()`.